# Simultaneously Sorting Multiple Rows of Data

Tags: sorting

What's the best way to alphabetically and simultaneously sort multiple rows of data that look like this:

```
FL  KS  NC  PA  SC  TX                                      AL  ID  LA  OK  
AK  FL  GA  KS  MD  NB  NY  PA  SC  TN  TX  WV              AL  IN  LA  MI  OK
```

to rows that look like this:

```
AL  FL  ID  KS  LA  NC  OK  PA  SC  TX                          
AK  AL  FL  GA  IN  KS  LA  MD  MI  NB  NY  OK  PA  SC  TN  TX  WV
```

The abbreviations are in separate cells, and the spaces between the groups are blank cells.

Comment: Cells, you say. Is this a biological problem?

Comment: What tool do you use? (Excel, Word, Chrome ...)

Comment: Sorry. This is an Excel document.